# mathpazo and pxfonts: equal sign and \neq look different

Tags: fonts, symbols, mathpazo

consider the following (minimal) example:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
$=$ $\ne$
\end{document}`

Is there any way I can make the "not equal" sign look exactly like a struck equal sign? Currently it does not.

Comment: You should load *either* the `mathpazo` package *or* the `pxfonts` package, but not both. As you've noticed, the math symbols provided by these two packages are not identical, and little good is going to come from (deliberately or inadvertently) mixing and (mis)matching them.

Comment: Owh, alright. Do you know the correct way to get symbols like \blacksquare when using mathpazo?

Comment: Yes: Issue the commands `\usepackage{amsfonts}` and 
`\DeclareMathSymbol{\blacksquare}{\mathord}{AMSa}{4}`. That's how the `pxfonts` package sets up the "black square" symbol; no reason to do it differently for `mathpazo`, right? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should load *either* the `mathpazo` package *or* the `pxfonts` package, but not both. As you've noticed, the math symbols provided by these two packages are not identical, and little good is going to come from (deliberately or inadvertently) mixing and (mis)matching them.

In a comment, you note that you need access to commands such as `\blacksquare`, which are set up by default in `pxfonts` but not in `mathpazo`. What to do if you decide to use the `mathpazo` package but need access to these additional commands? The definitions of these additional commands are provided in the file `pxfonts.sty`, and it shouldn't be too difficult to copy-and-paste the macros to your document's preamble. For instance, to get the `\blacksquare` command set up, you'd type the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\blacksquare}{\mathord}{AMSa}{4}
```

Happy TeXing!